# The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9847.) while registering new user in ejabberd using xmpp chat

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

i am  trying to register new user in ejabberd server for xmpp chat,but i am getting this error

```
 The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9847.)
```

when this method gets called

```
-(void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);

}
```

please help me out of this

Answer (score 1):

You are using a self-signed certificate, which is thus not trusted by your client.

You can implement your own trust verification algorithm in delegate method `xmppStream:didReceiveTrust:completionHandler:`

XMPPFramework documentation on security will give you some details: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/Security

By calling completion handler with value `@YES`, you are accepting the certificate. Beware not to make that change permanent in your code to avoid introducing security issue in your code.